# Deep Linkng: Open Multiple Apps with same host but different pathPrefix

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio, deep-linking

I am using [`Deep Linking`](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) in my application. But, now I have a requirement of opening two seperate apps on two seperate url's but same host like

```
http:www.google.com/Nexus5 - This should open App1

http:www.google.com/Nexus6 - This should open App2
```

The above url opens both the apps, but my requirement is that If I provide complete url like `http:www.google.com/Nexus5` then it should only show option to of App1.

So, its like if I pass on url

- `http:www.google.com/Nexus5` then only Nexus5 app should open and show option to browse the app. There should be no option to open Nexus6 app.
- Same way for `http:www.google.com/Nexus6` if I open Nexus6 url the it should not show option of Nexus5 App.

Below is my AndroidManifest file for that Activity,

```
<activity
            android:name=".DeepLinkDemo"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.google.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/Nexus5"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Now, this will run fine but if there is any other app with same host that means `www.google.com` I want to restrict that app from showing in the Browsable list(that other app will also be controlled by me)

So, is there anyway for achieving my above requirement?

Let, me know if anyone has any query!

Comment: Obviously it's working(the example that you had in the link)... what had you tried so far? How's your manifest looks like?

Comment: @Selvin updated the question!

Comment: *I want to restrict that app* ... you can't ... you may use `http:www.google.com/app1/Nexus6` ... `http:www.google.com/app2/Nexus6` and filter for `http:www.google.com/app1` in app1 and so on... but you can't restrict other app ... you may also open all "request" in first app and then open custom action in second app if avaible

Comment: @Selvin as I said that second app is also developed by me, I have the full access to that second app, so now is there any way to restrict it?

Answer (score -1):

You can use android:pathPattern to uniquely identify different application

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you provide a link to the documentation on this attribute to better explain how it's relevant to the question?